# Can't see any public WiFi

Tags: networking, kali-linux, internet

I cannot see any public WiFi using a USB Wifi adapter (TPLink-WN322G).

I've installed Kali Linux on my computer.

In my other PC and smartphone I can see WiFi connections.

After you connect to one of the public Wifi connections, you need to open browser and put your username and password from voucher.

But in my Kali Linux, I cannot see any SSID.

Answer (score 3):

Since Kali Linux is based on Debian, these instructions (from [this](https://wiki.debian.org/ath9k_htc) page) should help:

1. Add a "non-free" component to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, for example:

   ```
   # Debian 8 "Jessie"
   deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
   ```
2. Update the list of available packages and install the firmware-atheros package:

   ```
   # apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-atheros
   ```
3. Connect the device to your system. The ath9k_htc kernel module is automatically loaded for supported devices.
4. Configure your wireless interface as appropriate.

If the above does not help, using another USB WiFi interface might be a solution.

Comment: We prefer to have self-contained answers on [se] (of course you can provide links for non-essential detail). Just providing a link will be useless once bit-rot sets in.

Comment: OK, what's the preferred answer style then (I'm a stack exchange newb, don't even know how to move this to meta)? I don't feel copying that page would be in order, so would it be preferred to advise to search,  or just refrain from trying to answer when I can't provide a self-contained answer?

Comment: If you cannot make a self-contained answer, then posting the link as a comment could be an alternative, but you need have 50 rep to do so. But I think you can actually get the important information out of that page, without also copying the detail. As long as you attribute what you copy that's fine.